# Preaxiomatic evidence for $\forall a, b, c\in\mathbb R\colon a\cdot(b\cdot c) = (a\cdot b)\cdot c$

Tags: geometry, soft-question, intuition, real-numbers, associativity

Without working in a rigorous axiomatic system, how can you intuitively convince me that $a\cdot(b\cdot c) = (a\cdot b)\cdot c$ for all real numbers $a, b, c\in \mathbb R$? (Or, more generally, how can you convince me that the value of a product of real numbers $a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot\dots$ does not depend on how one puts the brackets?)

Remark on the use of axiomatic systems: Axiomatic systems of numbers are a very recent discovery, the first of them were discovered a little more than hundred years ago. At that time, the people already manipulated numbers with confident. So, how did they ensure that multiplication is associative and that the value of a product doesn't depend on how one puts the brackets? For instance, what geometric intuitions did they use?

Comment: The volume of a cube is the same no matter which way you calculate it. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Arthur: If a little description about the history is added and explained why this implies that the general associativity rule holds (i.e. the value of a product with more than 3 factors doesn't depend on how one puts the brackets), then yes. But I would also be interested in whether there are other mental images to intuitively understand the issue of associativity.